# What is the rationale for Bash ignoring errors when executing a script?

Tags: bash, error-handling

Bash -- and probably other shells too -- ignore any errors by default and just continue with the next command.  I wonder why the shell was designed that way.  After all, normally, one would want to abort a script in which every command needs the state generated by the previous.

Comment: It would be a pain to have interactive shells exit when you mistype.  You can use `set -e` to make shells exit on error.  Shells recognize that things can go wrong, even in scripts, and good scripts can detect and recover from the errors.  So your base hypothesis — that all (or even most) scripts should terminate on error — is really not correct.  There's also an element of "that's the way it is because that's the way it has been since, oh, the late 1970s" and no-one is about to change it now.  I occasionally use `set -e` when I want it.  Mostly I don't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this would also apply to other scripting languages, which normally abort on error.  I am not wondering about the shell's behaviour in interactive mode.

Comment: What do you mean that Bash doesn't abort on errors and other scripting languages do? Bash complains when there are syntax errors, just like other languages. Do you have a specific example? (I'm suspecting you're confusing Bash and the shell utilities).

Comment: @TorstenBronger: Could you provide few examples please?

Comment: One is supposed to write proper error handling in one's programming regardless of what language, shell, script or compiled executable, etc.  So your question has no merit IMO.

Comment: This really is somewhat disappointing.  No answers so far, only complaints and downvotes.  To be honest, I do not believe that the current contributors have not understood what I asked.

Comment: Four years later, I must state that Usenet participants willingly answered this question to me plausibly. In particular, they understood that the historical context of the 70’ies is important. So, my question may have been off-topic, but to tag it “opinion-based” is irritating.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reasons, something like:
Every check takes extra time. For better performance no additional check everytime and no popup "Are you sure [Yes] [No] [Ignore]".

You are afraid for code like

```
cd /
ls
cd $HOME/temp;
rm -rf *
```

Terrible when you do not have a temp dir (script made by a normal user and executed by root)!

Anybody who has root access must be aware of the responsibility and dangers (s)he has. That is why you shouldn't execute scripts you don't trust (don't have the current dir in your PATH). And the person who wrote that script is wrong as well. Without checks on `$?` the script should be changed into something like

```
cd / && ls
cd "${HOME}"/temp && rm -rf *
```

or

```
cd / && ls
if [ ${#HOME} -gt 1 ]; then
   rm -rf /"${HOME}"/temp/*
fi
```

Are these examples not a proof that exit-on-error would be better? I do not thinlk so. When Unix would fail exit on errors and you don't check everything, things can go terrible wrong with

```
cd /
ls
rm -rf /$HOME/temp/*
```

When HOME is set to / or a string with a space (ending with a space..) the last command might work. Always triple check your scripts, you are working with power.

Comment: No doubt that if you want security, you must not trust anything.  But besides that, tools normally are optimised for the more frequent or safer (not safe) use case.  And I think your examples rather show that bail-out-on-error would be the better default.  However, when shells were contrived, their creators thought differently.  Just a historical quirk or real rationale?